# Percentage calculation in php

Tags: php, math

I am trying to caluclate a percentage below (which by the way I need to be rounded up, but it keeps displaying 100. How can I calculate percentage in php using below's example:

```
    $totalmarks += (int)$questionData['questionmarks'];
    $studentmarks += (int)$questionData['studentmark'];
    $percentage = $studentmarks / $studentmarks * 100;

echo $percentage;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your formula is wrong. You are dividing `studentmarks`  by itself. It has to be divided by `totalmarks`. Currently its like saying `$percentage = 1/1 * 100`; which will always result in 100.

```
$percentage = ($studentmarks / $totalmarks) * 100;
$percentage = round($percentage,2);
```

Comment: Aorry bout that bad mistake, was doing this 5am and ended up going to sleep straight after haha. Sorry but thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way (IMHO) is to always **divide** totalmarks **with 100** and then **multiply** it with **value** you want percentage of (students)

```
$percentage = ($totalmarks / 100) * $studentmarks
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code may help you :)

```
$totalmarks += (int)$questionData['questionmarks'];
$studentmarks += (int)$questionData['studentmark'];
$percentage = ($studentmarks /   $totalmarks) * 100;
echo $percentage;
```

Answer (score 0):

To round up you need to use ceil()

```
echo ceil(($questionData['studentmark'] / $questionData['questionmarks']) *100);
```

Comment: You should replace questionmarks with studentmarks in your formula